# How to track when users have watched videos in WordPress with jQuery and Vimeo Player

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Basically, I'm trying to create a functionality where when the user watches my complete course video and it ends, I send an Ajax request to store some value to the user-meta and post-meta and print "you have already watched this".

Till now, I'm able to call jQuery event when the video ends and call Ajax to store value in post-meta but don't really find a way to store it the right way in database by which I can check if he watched the video already or not.

JS:

```
var iframe = document.querySelector('.embed_video');
var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    player.on('ended', function(){
        var likes = jQuery("#like").val();

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
            data: {"action": "post_word_count", "like":likes},
            success: function(data){
                //alert("Thank You For Liking This Post");
                jQuery("#imbed_into").html("You Have Watched Already!");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
function post_word_count(){
    $name = $_POST['like'];
    global $wpdb;
    global $user_ID, $post;
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    echo '<script>';
    echo 'alert($post_id)';
    echo '</script>';
    $wpdb->insert( 
        'wp_postmeta', 
        array( 
            'input_like' => $name,
            'meta_value' =>  $user_id,
        ), 
        array( 
            '%s'
        ) 
    );
    die();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far (as in actual code) and we might be able to help (see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: added my code can you please check?

Comment: you can save the users list with [update_post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta)

Comment: Let's do some basic debugging first. Is your AJAX function working? What does `console.log(data);` outputs? (Put that inside your `success` callback function).